# Determining the reason for difference in two FFTs

Tags: fft

I am trying to emulate FFT results from a software package using python (scypy). I am largely able to get the same trend, though there is an offset when comparing both FFT’s and I wanted to understand why this might be. The signals are 2min audio files, which are recorded at 12KHz. I split the 2 min audio file into 0.4s segments* (300 individual arrays), fft them with a hanning window and 0% overlap (multispectra), and then perform root mean square averaging to get the overall narrowband result. I note the trend shapes are the same but not the values ((1) below)?  The python multispectra are notably more sporadic ((2) below), whilst the dBFA individual multispectra are much less sporadic, and are more compact ((3) below). I presume the multispectra are the reason for the offset seen in (1)? What would the reason be for this?

*I require the resolution to be 2.5Hz, hence splitting the signal into 0.4s arrays
[image]

The settings in the software are as below;

[image]

..and my Python code is; (I can include all if required)

```
def stft(dfFrames, N, MaxHzLines, fs, minFreq, maxFreq):
  startIdx = int(np.floor((MaxHzLines / maxFreq) * minFreq))
  
  # Perform FFT on each windowed frame
  stft_frames = [fftpack.fft(x)[startIdx:MaxHzLines] for x in dfFrames['frames']]
  
  freq_axis = {idx: round(m*fs/N, 5) for idx, m in enumerate(range(0, MaxHzLines))}  
  
  dfSTFT = pd.DataFrame({'freq_axis': freq_axis})

  dfSTFT = dfSTFT.rename(index=freq_axis)

  for idx, frame in enumerate(stft_frames):
    dfSTFT[idx] = frame

  dfSTFT = dfSTFT.drop('freq_axis', axis=1)

  return dfSTFT


# data = numpy array of len 1440000 - 2min audio file at 12000samples/s
# FFT params
minFreq = 0
maxFreq = 2000
numLines = 801

# 4800 will get 2.5Hz resolution
N = 4800
fs = 12000
fs_res = fs/N
MaxHzLines = int(maxFreq/fs_res) + 1

# Windowing params
overlap = 0
window = N / fs

# COMPUTED Parameters
skip = window * (1 - overlap)

# A-weight correction (to account for human sensitivity to particular frequencies).
b, a = a_weightingFilter(fs)
data = lfilter(b, a, data)

# Enframe 2-minute files by window length (resulting in 300 arrays)
dfFrames = enframe(data,
                   int(skip * 12000),
                   int(window * 12000))

# FFT Analysis
dfSTFT = stft(dfFrames, N, MaxHzLines, fs, minFreq, maxFreq)

# Get rms averaged narrowband spectra
dfSTFT_multi = 2/N*abs(dfSTFT)
dfSTFT_narrow = np.sqrt(np.mean(dfSTFT_multi**2, axis=1))

# Get dB values and add to dict
dfSTFT_narrow = 20*np.log10(dfSTFT_narrow)
dfSTFT_multi = 20*np.log10(dfSTFT_multi)
```

Is there anything obvious I should be doing here to reduce this offset / get the same values?

Comment: The offset over the entire spectrum is likely caused by differing Fourier transform normalization. [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html)'s implementation appears to not do any normalization, so try multiplying the other result by $N$ or $\sqrt{N}$. Alternatively, you can normalize the scipy result by these factors instead.